# PHP - from DB to Array format

Tags: php, arrays

I AM A PHP SUPER NOOB.

I am trying to extract data using PHP from a MySQL db.
I want to take the 'PersonName' column and 'Count' column and place them into an array.

PHP Code (so far):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, --SQL CODE HERE--);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$data = $row['colName'];
}
```

I have been using print_r to print out my $data and i have been getting results such as
`"Array ( [0] => Fred [Name] => Fred [1] => 11 [count(*)] => 11 )"`
in my attempts. This format has not been working for me.

### Goal:

I want to obtain an array (or 2 arrays) that contain the data from the 2 columns mentioned above.

I need it to be in either of the following formats:
 1. One-Array Solution: [['Fred', 3], ['Bob', 5], ['Ted', 10]]
 2. Two-Array Solution: ['Fred', 'Bob', 'Ted'] & [3, 5, 10]

### Question:

How should my PHP code be modified in order to bring data in from the database into the array formats that I am looking for?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How do i reach my goal?

Comment: Sounds like homework... Try `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)` and then put `$data[0]` or `$data[1]` into one or two arrays that store your final results.

Comment: wish i ever had homework like this.  
dont really understand several different parts of what you suggested.  
Could you expound upon the use of MYSQL_NUM, $data[#] usages, and what you mean by putting those array elements into one or two arrays

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dataArray[] = $row;
}
```

Display it this way in your HTML and you will understand how to use the data from the array

```
<?php print_r($dataArray); ?>
```

Comment: have not been able to figure it out, although I have been trying various things and testing it using print_r.